# Anyone have pointers on how to access a touchscreen on Raspberry Pi with Android Things?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, touchscreen, lcd, android-things

This question is broken into two parts:

- Are there guides on which touchscreens 'work out of the box' with Raspberry Pi3 + Android Things? Its easy enough to stick HDMI screen on get output, but touchscreen is not so clear. I'm reading conflicting things about user-drivers and peripheral IO. But one things is clear, we can roll our own kernel-level HAL driver.
- Second this likely depends on the answer above, is it correct to say that we can use the standard android UI classes for capturing motion and input?

Comment: from the docs "But one things is clear, we can roll our own kernel-level HAL driver." is wrong. The docs say: `Note: You cannot customize the behavior of device drivers in the Linux kernel or Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) to add new functionality to a device.`

Comment: I didn't have any problems with a `Waveshare HDMI` display with an additional USB/power-input for touchscreen.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say we cannot use roll our own HAL driver. Really bad typo!

Answer (score 1):

- We successfully tested the official [Raspberry Pi touchscreen](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/) with the [simpleui sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-simpleui).
- Yes standard android UI class could be used to capture motion and input, you can also combine those with external peripheral (like push buttons, capacitive sensors, joysticks) with [input user-drivers](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/input.html).

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, good to know that touchscreen works. Is that because it uses the DSI interface and Android Things library works with that 'out of the box'? I have another touchscreen by Kuman, but does not use DSI. It's not clear to me if there needs to be a driver that to work. The simplui sample has a button listener for the various checkboxes, so the assumption is there is already events being picked up somewhere by the OS.